# What happens to boosts that are obviated by the narrative?

Tags: fate-core, fate-accelerated, boosts

During a [quick Fate session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/an-swashbuckling-duel), two characters were engaged in a duel, during which an onlooker was hurled into the fray, resulting in one duelist gaining the boost ***Petticoats and Fluff*** on the other. Shortly thereafter, both characters moved to a different zone, without the boost being invoked.

At that point, according to the events of the story, being temporarily tangled up in another person's underwear isn't really relevant anymore (barring the amusing idea that they're being dragged around as the swordfight progresses); however, as boosts can be generated as rewards for success with style, it doesn't seem right to remove them from play without granting the bonus to a roll, but at the same time, the narrative may not ever justify using them again.

What happens to an unclaimed boost when the story changes to obviate it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Boosts are a super transient type of aspect. [Fate Core 58]

And if the aspect is no longer applicable, the GM is encouraged to let it go/clean it up.

> Finally, if at any point it simply makes no sense for a situation aspect to be in play, get rid of it. [Fate Core 78]

So, you should feel free to eliminate the boost without any guilt: situation aspects disappear all the time, and boosts should disappear even quicker.

For something humorous, however, I'd let the player use their boost in an appropriately related scene as a transient version of **Declare A Story Detail** [Fate Core 80].

Comment: As a slight aside, and to assuage any guilt the GM feels, you may allow the boost to be used to defend the move to another zone in the first place, if that fits.